# Best choice for very simple lookup table

Tags: c

I am reading a file with commands that are [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9], i.e., two chars. There is a total of 43 different commands, and I would like to transform the two chars to a number (1..43).

How would you proceed? I was thinking on creating an array of 43 unsigned shorts (two bytes) each corresponding to the two chars of each command, and then doing something like:

```
//char1: first char of cmd, char2: second char of cmd, lut: array of 43 shorts.
unsigned short tag;
tag = (char1 << 8) | char2;
for(int i=1;i<=43;i++) {
    if(tag==lut[i-1]) return i;
}
return 0;
```

The thing is I'm not sure if this is the best way for doing what I want. I guess that with just 43 elements it won't matter, but that list might increase in the future.

Comment: could use a hashmap to map from command strings to number

Comment: What is a "LUT"? "Look-up table"?

Comment: It really depends what you are going to do with that data structure. There is not one perfect data structure for every purpose.

Comment: You can start with the very simple and short approach you use here, and change it if performance or flexibility turns out to be an issue.

Comment: Unrelated, but: whether you borrowed the idiom `for(int i=1;i<=43;i++) .. lut[i-1]` from another programming language or you came up with it by yourself, please un-learn it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Jongware I just did it so the 0 is free for "not found", but I guess I can return a signed value and use -1.

Comment: Due to effects of memory caching it can be expected that a simple linear search will outperform anything else for tens of thousands of elements, assuming everything you need to look at is in contiguous memory.  Also, for your example you would want to use int data type to store your key values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I used on an old project. One big drawback to this method is the lookup table and enum are dependent on each other and need to be kept synchronized. I got this method from an online article quite a few years ago, but don't remember where. This is a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CMDSIZE 2

const char* cmd_table[] = { "qu",
                            "qr",
                            "fi",
                            "he"};

enum { CMD_QUIT,
       CMD_QUIT_RESTART,
       CMD_FILE, 
       CMD_HELP,
       CMD_NONE };

int lookup(char command[])
{
  int i = 0;
  int cmdlength = strlen(command);
  for (i = 0; i < cmdlength; i++)
  {
    command[i] = tolower(command[i]);
  }

  const int valid_cmd = sizeof cmd_table / sizeof *cmd_table;

  for (i = 0; i < valid_cmd; i++)
  {
    if (strcmp(command, cmd_table[i]) == 0)
        return i;
  }
  return CMD_NONE;
}

int main()
{
    char key_in[BUFSIZ];
    char command[CMDSIZE+1];
// Wait for command
    do
    {
        printf("Enter command: ");
        fgets(key_in, BUFSIZ, stdin);   
        key_in[strlen(key_in)-1] = '\0';
        strncpy(command, key_in, CMDSIZE);
        command[CMDSIZE] = '\0';
        switch (lookup(command))
        {
            case CMD_QUIT:
        printf ("quit\n");
                break;
            case CMD_QUIT_RESTART:
                printf ("quit & restart\n");
                break;
            case CMD_FILE:
                printf ("file\n");
                break;
            case CMD_HELP:
                printf("help\n");
                break;
            case CMD_NONE:
                if(strcmp(key_in, ""))
                    printf("\"%s\" is not a valid command\n", key_in);
                break;
        }
    } while (strcmp(command, "qu"));
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I found the article I mentioned:

https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/65343/lookup-tables-how-to-perform-a-switch-using-a-string